# javascript multidimensional array help

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

should this work? Am i  missing something?

```
var this_array = [

    [],

    [
        [],
        [
            [],
            [
                [],
                [
                    ['50.3']
                ],
                [
                    ['12.0']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [],
        [
            [],
            [
                [],
                [
                    ['85.3']
                ],
                [
                    ['31.1']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(this_array[1][1][1][1][0]);
}
```

Comment: Yes. This should work. You are not missing something. Keep coding.

Comment: Running your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ before posting it and using Code formatting (there's a button for it above the editor) makes it more readable for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ny8ze/

Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It works for me:

'50.3'

Did you get an error?